# Azure Event Hub - Outgoing message/bytes doesn't increase after increasing throughput units and IEventProcessor instances

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have an EventHub instance with 200 partitions (Dedicated cluster). Originally, I have a consumer group with 70 instances of IEventProcessor + 1 throughput unit.

It appears that I can only have 30M outgoing messages per hour while there are double of that amount for incoming. So I increased to 20 throughput units and 100 processor instances. But the outgoing messages don't increase beyond 30M. I don't see any throttle messages.

Are there other EventHub limits that I should adjust here?

EDIT 1:

After setting prefetch and batch size to 1000 I still only see moderate increase: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZsQr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I can recommend to check and do:

1. Increase batch and prefetch size.
2. Check client side resources like CPU and available memory. See if there is any high resource utilization which may become a bottleneck.
3. If hosts are on in a different region than the eventhub, network latency can slow down the receives. Co-locate hosts with eventhub if so.

Consider creating a support ticket so PG can do a proper investigation.

Comment: Thanks. What is PG? I already did 2 and 3. I found out that I didn't set the 2 properties for `EventProcessorOptions` so I just did it. Looks like outgoing increase substantially. Let's wait a few hour to see if that works

Comment: PG - Product Group. Monitor client side CPU and memory as well. Something may eventually become the new bottleneck.

Comment: It appears that when I increase the batch size, the throughput go up a lot but then fall down again? Take a look at the screenshot. https://imgur.com/fVil02N

Comment: Apperantly you have another bottleneck now. Try measuring the process duration. Since client now receives larger batches, each ProcessEventsAsync call takes longer to complete. Experiment with removing process logic from the picture and see if it helps.

Comment: I split the events and use `Task.Run()` (C#) to schedule on multiple threads. But I still `await` the return task. Should I not `await`?

Comment: Have you already measured average time taken to process messages? Better to pinpoint the issue first before doing some experimental changes in your code.I don't know what sort of heavy lifting you are doing during the process like is it CPU bound or thread bound etc.

Comment: I did some experimental changes. If I removed all the processing then outgoing messages increase many folds. My logic is to split events into groups and write each group to disk in separate files. I already use Task.Run(). But I don't know if not `await` is safe. If I don't do `await`, throughput increases, which makes sense

Comment: Can you help me understand your per partition throughput? Are math figures correct here? 60M per hour = 16K per second which is around 100 messages per partition per second. What is the typical batch size you have observed when processing code removed? How many disk I/O calls on average generated by single batch?

Comment: batch size is usually max value which is 2000 right now. There can be up to 100-200 groups of events in 1 batch. Each group will be written to separate text files

Comment: So that sounds like each batch initiates 100 to 200 SQL writes. I think what you can do is parallel SQL writes. Basically, create a list of tasks where each task will do a write to the SQL and wait all tasks with await Task.WhenAll(tasks). See if this reduces the blocking time for SQL I/O.

Comment: To close this thread: I setup a concurrent queue and use the Processor to put events onto the queue and a scheduled jobs to dequeue from it. The machines has enough power to process events, but EH send events in burst so it gets OutOfMemory exception. Now with a queue, Processor can put events very fast but wait if the queue get too long